# Are WiFi, audio, video modules included in the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot-loader, hardware-compatibility, netbook

I have an old netbook based on WM8880 SoC (https://laptop.fossee.in/) which used to run lubuntu 16.04  (customised heavily by the [fossee](https://laptop.fossee.in/) team) via Uboot bootloader fairly well, one fine day it said I could upgrade to 18.04 so without even thinking I did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

The problem starts just after that,

the wifi hardware doesn't show up

The backlight keys stopped working

`sudo apt-get update` or `install` doesn't work I end up getting

```
sudo apt-get update  --fix-missing
Err:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com'
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Sound no longer works etc..

Here's the hardware details, from `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1017:1006 Speedy Industrial Supplies, Pte., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and `lspci`

```
00:01.0 IDE interface: VIA Technologies, Inc. Device 1359
00:02.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6105/VT6106S [Rhine-III] (rev 84)
00:04.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 90)
00:05.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 90)
00:06.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev 90)
```

And the output of `dmesg | grep wifi`

```
[    3.735124] wifi_power_ctrl 1, delay:0
[    3.735158] use default wifi gpio: susgpio1
[    3.735179] request gpio:156 for wifi success!!!
[    3.735189] power on wifi
[    3.735282] wifi_power_ctrl 0, delay:0
[    3.735310] use default wifi gpio: susgpio1
[    3.735328] power down wifi
```

The WiFi card I have is a Realtek 8152 as noticed from the board image [here](https://ibb.co/Gsbyxgq).
I tried to roll back by requesting the original firmware from the team but they don't have one and the online copy seems to be [deleted](https://laptop.fossee.in/applications/how-to-reinstall-fossee-os).

The team has released kernel sources and some other tools [here](https://laptop.fossee.in/links)

Is there any way to get the lost functionality working again?

I was thinking of compiling the kernel from the source and try to install it?

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Does the WM8880 drive your WiFi too? If not, what card is the WiFi and what does the kernel report it is? (`lsusb` or `lspci`, and maybe the relevant part from `dmesg` too). Please put this information [into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/507154/edit) so that it's easy for us to help you.

Comment: First of all, that's why you do backups before doing an upgrade. Second, you need to provide more information about your hardware to get help as said by @roaima

Comment: @roaima the output of `lsusb` and `lspci` are here https://pastebin.com/zvbsQhCV I am trying to get to the hardware to know  if there is a separate wifi card, I will report my findings as soon as possible

Comment: Unfortunately the extract from `dmesg` is no use whatsoever. You need to look for the part that shows the kernel finding the wifi card, and how it is initialising it (assuming it does so).

Comment: Ah. You've a Realtek 8152.

Comment: @roaima thanks for the edit, I'll keep that in mind, also I managed to get a pic of the hardware, [https://ibb.co/Gsbyxgq] , It turns out that like your guess, the card indeed is Realtek 8152

Comment: Actually, not a guess. It was the line from `lsusb` - `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.`. If you then search for `0bda:8152 Realtek` you'll find confirmation in the matches (the `0bda:8152` is a vendor and product code; it's different for every type of USB device out there - products branded the same on the outside may have different hardware implementations - so it's an good way to determine what hardware you have).